# Relationship between docker image and its tar representation

Tags: docker

I took a docker `ubuntu` image and exported as a tar file. I then went on to inspect that tar file and found that it contains basically executables and shared libraries. The boot directory is empty but that's no surprise.

Is it correct to say that a docker image is basically a tar file with a sha1 commit associated with it, just as in `git`? I am very confused by the file system of `image` and layers of `image`.

Comment: You usually don't export or save Docker images; in standard use, you can push and pull them to and from registries, but they don't exist as standalone files.  The actual on-disk representation is installation-specific and you can't directly interact with it.

Comment: Is there any article that touches upon docker image's on-disk representation?

Comment: you can check the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) to get more info about container